# Why doesn't Relay's NODE_DELETE update the list of remaining Nodes

Tags: relay, mutation

I've got a `NODE_DELETE` Mutation that removes a `Category` from the list of categories. Even though it provides the correct `deletedIDFieldname`, the list of categories doesn't get updated until I refresh the page.

Do I miss something here? Thanks for any hint!

```
import Relay from 'react-relay';

export default class DeleteCategoryMutation extends Relay.Mutation {

  getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`mutation{deleteCategory}`;
  }
  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on DeleteCategoryPayload {
        category {
          id
        },
        viewer {
          allCategories
        }
      }
    `;
  }
  getConfigs() {
    return [{
      type: 'NODE_DELETE',
      parentName: 'viewer',
      parentID: this.props.viewer.id,
      connectionName: 'allCategories',
      deletedIDFieldName: 'category{id}',
    }];
  }
  getVariables() {
    return {
      id: this.props.categoryId,
    };
  }
  getOptimisticResponse () {
    return {
      deletedId: this.props.categoryId,
      viewer: this.props.viewer.id,
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need expand your `getFatQuery` a little further like the following.

```
 getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on DeleteCategoryPayload {
        category {
          id
        },
        viewer {
          allCategories(first: 1000) {
            edges
          }
        }
      }
    `;
 }
```

Hope this helps. But I agree that this is somewhat tricky and Relay should help you in situations like these...